# Function "undefined" message in Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Codecademy

Tags: javascript, project

This function is supposed to produce exactly 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' (input is not case sensitive). But when I put in the wrong value (ie. 'papers' with an extra 's'), my function prints the error message (expected) AND a message saying "undefined" (not expected).

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' ||
      userInput === 'paper' ||
      userInput === 'scissors') {
        return userInput;
      } else {
        console.log('Please enter rock, paper, or scissors.')
      }
}
console.log(getUserChoice('papers')); #prints 'paper' correctly if paper is the input
```

EDIT: I updated the question to be clearer and I already found the answer. It has to do with the difference between console.log and return.

Comment: This might be better suited for the corresponding forum topic for the project in Codecademy, as there are other people in there working on the same project to converse with.

Comment: This isn't Java.

Comment: What *should* the function return when the input is invalid?

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. This was my first time posting a question so I appreciate all of your input.

Comment: `getUserChoice('papers')` will return `undefined`. Try `getUserChoice('paper')`. Also, Javascript uses `//` for line comments, not `#`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your console.loging the error message rather then returning it

and when it ask you to 'Please enter rock, paper, or scissors' your not returning anything and thus the return is undefined.

so switch

`console.log('Please enter rock, paper, or scissors')`

to

`return 'Please enter rock, paper, or scissors';`

---

Comment: I just figured it out, too! Thank you for your response.